# Eclipse CDT: Fatal Error. No Such File or Directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have looked at all other answers before posting this question. Nothing seem to work.

I want to include header files from a workspace into my project and I have included the path at **C/C++ General, Paths and Symbols, Includes** section as seen from the image below. The file can be seen in the includes folder of the project but it still throws a missing file error.

[image: s]

Surprisingly it works when I go to **C/C++ build settings** and select "**Generate makefiles automatically**" button but this creates yet another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181478/how-to-change-default-build-directory-path-in-eclipse-cdt-when-generate-makefil).

Please do let me know how to solve either of these two issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41794456/141719

Comment: @HighCommander4: Thanks for pointing it out. But, I did mention in my issue that if I do the above mentioned change at C/C++ Build Settings, I am stuck with another [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181478/how-to-change-default-build-directory-path-in-eclipse-cdt-when-generate-makefil). Kindly let me know how to solve this other issue.

Comment: Do you have a "Tool Settings" tab in Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings?

Comment: @HighCommander4: If I select "Generate Makefiles Automatically" at C/C++ Build Settings, I then have the "Tool Settings" tab. Else I do not have it.

Comment: Ok, so I would suggest: (1) apply the workaround from the other question. (2) Add your include paths in Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes.